# jasper reeport file not found

Tags: java, file, jasper-reports

I am trying to use my NetBeans to print pdf file from jasper report but it gives a file not found exception

```
 try {
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("gdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
        ods.setUser("user");
        ods.setPassword("123456");
        InputStream s= new FileInputStream(new File("Tree.jrxml"));
        JasperDesign ds = new FXMLLoader().load(s);
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ds);
        HashMap parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("id",idtxt.getText());
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters ,ods.getConnection());
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (new File ("REP.pdf"));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jp, out);
        ods.getConnection().close();
        s.close();
        out.close();

    }catch(Exception x){
        System.out.println(x.toString());
    }


 the exception :
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Tree.jrxml (The system cannot find the file specified)

all files needed in src folder and  all libraries imported as well

- > > src
  >
  > ```
  >  Myrep.java
  >
  >  Tree.jrxml
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it's the wrong path. Try to put Tree.jrxml in resource marked directory:)
In Java usually src/main/resources, and your code is in src/main/java dir.

Comment: what to do exactly ? all my file in \src\myrep\*